# My CSS isn't responding to ID and Class identifiers

Tags: html, css, class

I'm having a very strange problem. I'm simply trying to use Ids and Classes to edit my HTML with CSS and for some reason it's not being recognized. Here is the HTML I've used.

```
<p class="Benefits" ><center>Benefits of First Person Shooters</center></p>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.Benefits {
font-size: 60px;
}
```

Id's won't respond either.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, it's probably some other CSS element with different `font-size` that has a better matching for this element.

Comment: The browser has auto-corrected your faulty HTML when building the DOM – `p` can not contain `center`, so the browser closes the opened `p` element _before_ then `center` element, and therefor everything inside the `center` element is not inside the `p` element any more, and therefor the font-size does not get applied. And btw. `center` is deprecated, you should not use it any more `- use CSS for formatting only, not outdated HTML elements.

Comment: Got it, thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `center` tag inside a paragraph creates invalid markup which browsers try to fix. Also:

> The 'center' tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

```css
.Benefits {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="Benefits">Benefits of First Person Shooters</p>
```

Comment: Whoops, I'm pretty new and not sure which tags are deprecated and which ones are still commonplace. Thanks mate!

Comment: No problem, mate! Whenever in doubt, try to stick to the standard ones: div, p, span... Here's a nice article with a big list that you might find helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: @dippas I was just writing you an apology for being too harsh in the comments. Thank you for being such a good sport! Added a few ups for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Added center selector has the same font-size as Benefits class

```
   .Benefits, center  {
      font-size: 60px;
    }

    <p class="Benefits" ><center>Benefits of First Person Shooters</center></p>
```

Comment: That's **not** a solution since the Benefits class is absolutely useless and only the rules for center are applied (which is why it works).

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the HTML, you'll notice that the center tag is placed OUTSIDE of your paragraph. Add the class/id to the center tag rather than the paragraph, or use CSS to center the text rather than having a center tag.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's within the "center" element.  Put your class within "center".